# Only showing last item in array

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to figure out why its only showing the last child_links in the roster, events, and social objects. I've included the site that has the print_r of the array function. Any help would be appreciated.

http://kansasoutlawwrestling.com/

```
function getSubMenuPages()
{
    $this->db->select('id');
    $this->db->where('short_name', 'mainnav'); 
    $query = $this->db->get('site_menu_structures'); 
    $menu_id = $query->row()->id; 

    $this->db->select('id, short_name, is_category');
    $this->db->where('menu_structure_id', $menu_id); 
    $query = $this->db->get('site_menu_structures_links');

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) 
    {
        $linksArray = $query->result();
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r( $linksArray );
        echo "</pre>";
        foreach ($linksArray as $key => $link)
        {
            if ($link->is_category == 'Yes')
            {
                $this->db->select('link_name, site_content_pages_id, link_url');
                $this->db->where('site_menu_structures_links_id', $link->id); 
                $query = $this->db->get('site_menu_structures_links_children');
                if ($query->num_rows() > 0) 
                {
                    foreach ($query->result() as $row)
                    {
                        $site_content_page_id = $row->site_content_pages_id;
                        $linksArray[$key]->child_links = array();
                        if ($site_content_page_id != 0)
                        {
                            $this->db->select('content_page_name, permalink');
                            $this->db->where('id', $site_content_page_id); 
                            $query = $this->db->get('site_content_pages');
                            if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
                            {
                                $row = $query->row(); 
                                $linksArray[$key]->child_links = array(
                                                                'link_name'  => $row->content_page_name,
                                                                'link_url' => $row->permalink
                                                             );
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $linksArray[$key]->child_links = array(
                                                                'link_name'  => $row->link_name,
                                                                'link_url' => $row->link_url
                                                             );
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return $linksArray;

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you loop here:

```
foreach ($query->result() as $row)
                    {
                        $site_content_page_id = $row->site_content_pages_id;
                        $linksArray[$key]->child_links = array();
                        if ($site_content_page_id != 0)
                        {
```

you're inside another loop, so at each passage of this loop here the $key remains the same.

So, **1st external loop**, ex. $key = 'key1'; I'll use some pseudo code to give the idea:

```
foreach results as row:
  (loop nr 1):
     linksarray['key1'] = empty array.
     linksarray['key1'] = value;
  (loop nr 2):
     linksarray['key1'] = empty array
     linksarray['key1'] = value2
endforeach;
```

**2nd external loop**, $Key = 'key2'

```
   foreach results as row:
      (loop nr 1):
         linksarray['key2'] = empty array.
         linksarray['key2'] = value;
      (loop nr 2):
         linksarray['key2'] = empty array
         linksarray['key2'] = value2
    endforeach;
```

I might have mis-looked something in all those loops, it's evening here and I'm a bit tired :)

---

Oh, and a piece of advice: your code gets easily a bit difficult to read; a small improvement would be to omit the table name (as it's not necessary), especially when it's so long; moreover, in AR you can omit the "from" clause and also chain method.

So, for ex., this:

```
$this->db->select('site_menu_structures_links_children.link_name, site_menu_structures_links_children.site_content_pages_id, site_menu_structures_links_children.link_url');
$this->db->from('site_menu_structures_links_children');
$this->db->where('site_menu_structures_links_children.site_menu_structures_links_id', $link->id);
$query = $this->db->get();
```

Could be easily rewritten as:

```
$query = $this->db->select('link_name,site_content_pages_id,link_url')
                  ->where('site_menu_structures_links_id',$link->id)
                  ->get('site_menu_structures_links_children');
```

Doing this might help you in identifying out the general code flow, spotting out the various runs

## **UPDATE**

Try this

```
function getSubMenuPages()
{
    $this->db->select('id');
    $this->db->where('short_name', 'mainnav'); 
    $query = $this->db->get('site_menu_structures'); 
    $menu_id = $query->row()->id; 

    $this->db->select('id, short_name, is_category');
    $this->db->where('menu_structure_id', $menu_id); 
    $query2 = $this->db->get('site_menu_structures_links');

    if ($query2->num_rows() > 0) 
    {
        $linksArray = $query2->result();
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r( $linksArray );
        echo "</pre>";
        foreach ($linksArray as $key => $link)
        {
            if ($link->is_category == 'Yes')
            {
                $this->db->select('link_name, site_content_pages_id, link_url');
                $this->db->where('site_menu_structures_links_id', $link->id); 
                $query3 = $this->db->get('site_menu_structures_links_children');
                if ($query3->num_rows() > 0) 
                {
                    $linksArray[$key]->child_links = array();
                    foreach ($query3->result() as $row)
                    {
                        $site_content_page_id = $row->site_content_pages_id;
                        //$linksArray[$key]->child_links = array();
                        if ($site_content_page_id != 0)
                        {
                            $this->db->select('content_page_name, permalink');
                            $this->db->where('id', $site_content_page_id); 
                            $query4 = $this->db->get('site_content_pages');
                            if ($query4->num_rows() > 0)
                            {
                                $row = $query4->row(); 
                                $linksArray[$key]->child_links[]['link_name'] = $row->content_page_name;
                                $linksArray[$key]->child_links[]['link_url'] = $row->permalink;
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $linksArray[$key]->child_links[]['link_name'] = $row->link_name;
                            $linksArray[$key]->child_links[]['link_url'] = $row->link_url;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return $linksArray;

}
```

basically, I moved the property assigment `$linksArray[$key]->child_links = array();` outside the loop. Being followed by another loop, which can possibly have more values, I've created an index for each loop:

```
$linksArray[$key]->child_links[]['link_name'] = $row->content_page_name;
$linksArray[$key]->child_links[]['link_url'] = $row->permalink;
```

Comment: Great work but its not sinking into me very well. I'm trying to figure out how to apply it to my own.

Comment: Thank you I did that and will update with my new code. Still don't have a fix yet.

Comment: @JeffDavidson updated my answer with a suggestion; cannot test it, though, give it a try

Comment: I did and the only issue was it made a new array with link_name and link_url they should be on the same one.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing this block of code:

```
$this->db->select('link_name, site_content_pages_id, link_url');
$this->db->where('site_menu_structures_links_id', $link->id); 
$query = $this->db->get('site_menu_structures_links_children');
if ($query->num_rows() > 0) 
{
    $linksArray[$key]->child_links = array();

    foreach ($query->result() as $row)
    {
        $site_content_page_id = $row->site_content_pages_id;

        if ($site_content_page_id != 0)
        {
            $this->db->select('content_page_name, permalink');
            $this->db->where('id', $site_content_page_id); 
            $query2 = $this->db->get('site_content_pages');
            if ($query2->num_rows() > 0)
            {
                $row2 = $query2->row(); 
                array_push($linksArray[$key]->child_links, array(
                                                'link_name'  => $row2->content_page_name,
                                                'link_url' => $row2->permalink
                                             ));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            array_push($linksArray[$key]->child_links, array(
                                                'link_name'  => $row->link_name,
                                                'link_url' => $row->link_url
                                             ));
        }
    }
}
```